# I can't figure out why this code is returning a "list index out of range" error

Tags: python, list

I can't work out why this code (for removing vowels from a word) is returning a "list index out of range error. Any suggestions ?

```
    def anti_vowel(string):
        my_list = list(string) 
        for i in range(0,len(my_list)-1): #For loop iterates over the entire list
            for c in "aeiouAEIOU": #For loop iterates over all vowels" 
                if my_list[i] == c:
                    my_list = my_list.pop(i) 
    return my_list
print anti_vowel("Hello")
```

Comment: `range(0,5)` returns `[0,1,2,3,4]`. You don't need the -1.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = my_list.pop(i)
```

You are removing items from the list in this statement, so as it loops over the original length of the list, there are now fewer items in the list than there were to start.

You probably want to copy the list before iterating over it, in order to iterate over the original list but remove items from the new list.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over and mutating  your list  so it is getting smaller than the original length:

```
my_list = my_list.pop(i)
```

Use a list comp:

```
def anti_vowel(string):
        my_list = list(string)
        return [ x for x in my_list if x not in "aeiouAEIOU"]
```

If you want  a string returned use `join` on your list:

```
 "".join([ x for x in my_list if x not in "aeiouAEIOU"])
```

Using a list comp  `[ x for x in my_list if x not in "aeiouAEIOU"]` we filter the letters and only keep the ones that are not in our vowel string.

Or [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

```
 def anti_vowel(s):
        return s.translate(None,"aeiouAEIOU")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting up the for loop to go from 0 to the length of the original list, then popping items off the list within the loop - so by the time you get round the loop again, the length has changed.